# Laravel Eloquent get only one specific field with relationship and paginate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here my code :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service:name','conciergeries.network:name')->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)->simplePaginate(100);
        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];
        return $res;
```

I need to get only the network name and not all datas of "conciergeries" and "network" because actually is too heavy.

I have tried some things like

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service:name','conciergeries.network:name')->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)->pluck('network.name')->simplePaginate(100);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Ok, and what is your question? Doesn't it work?

Comment: The output is all datas of "conciergeries" and "network", I need to get only the network name

Answer (score 0):

When using eager loading with specific columns, you should always include the `id` column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

So try this instead:

```php
$prestations = Prestation::with(
        'service:id,name',
        'conciergeries:id,network_id',
        'conciergeries.network:id,name'
    )
    //->orderBy(...
```

Don't forget to add/modify any other relevant foreign keys you use, I just guessed these keys.

Comment: Thank's for your suggest, i get this message : message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
What do you mean by "Don't forget to add/modify any other relevant foreign keys you use" ?
If i remove the second line 'conciergeries:id,network_id' it's okay but i get all of datas and not only que network id and name.

Comment: @Tony what is your foreign/local keys on `prestations`, `services`, `conciergeries` and `networks` tables? you should add all these relevant keys.

Comment: Oh okay ! This should be a reason that the output is not only the network name and id ?

Comment: @Tony have you tries this? could you figure this out? what is your output now?

Comment: The output is the same than before, i don't get only the name and id, i get all datas of network and conciergeries

Comment: @Tony I think you should edit your question and add your models' relations and table structures, for us to be able to help more.